# How do you query a MS SQL database's information schema

Tags: sql-server, pdo, zend-framework2

I am reworking an application into ZF2 and ran into a snag. I am using PDO with sqlsrv drivers and I need to run the following query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

My query function looks like this:

```
public function getTables()
{      
    $sql = new Sql($this->dbAdapter);
    $select = $sql->select();

    $select->columns(array('TABLE_NAME'))
            ->from('INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES')
            ->order('TABLE_NAME');

    $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);

    $results = $statement->execute();

    return $results;
}
```

I keep getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES'.

Is there a special way it must be encoded? I can query standard DB tables all day and have no problem.

Thanks in advance for any recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

This query also give you the all tables.Try this

```
 SELECT name 
 FROM sys.objects 
 WHERE type='U' ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `sys.objects`, you can also use `sys.tables`.

```
SELECT
     name
FROM
    sys.tables AS t
ORDER BY
     name
```

In case you need the schema too, check this query out.

```
SELECT
    N'[' + s.name + N'].[' + o.name + ']'--I'm not sure what you are doing with your results, but I concatonated the schema with the table name
FROM
    sys.schemas AS s INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
        ON
            s.schema_id = o.schema_id
WHERE
    o.type = N'U'
```

Comment: sys.objects and sys.tables are not working for me in ZF2. If I run a query with a manually created PDO object it works fine. I am constructing the db adapter from a factory in ZF2 and in turn, constructing the sql object with the returned dbAdapter. When I var_dump the statement I get: 'SELECT "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES"."TABLE_NAME" AS "TABLE_NAME" FROM "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES" ORDER BY "TABLE_NAME" ASC' which seems to be in proper form. For sys.tables and sys.objects it says the same thing. Definitely has me a little confused. Worst case I can just run it manually from PDO.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with the Zend Framework (I probably should be though). What's a PDO?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TableGateway you can easily get the Meta Data using the TableGateway Feature\MetadataFeature. More on that here -> https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.db.table-gateway.html#tablegateway-features

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Hopefully this will help others. When accessing multiple schemas on a MSSQL database server or an Oracle database server the global configuration must turn off the 'quote_identifiers' option to work with the default configuration of the database servers.

For example the config/autoload/global.php would contain:

```
return array(
'db' => array(
    'driver'         => 'Pdo',
    'dsn'            => "sqlsrv:Server=DATABASE_SERVER;Database=DATABASE;",
    'charset'        => 'UTF-8',
    'pdotype'        => 'sqlsrv',
    'platform_options' => array('quote_identifiers' => false),
),);
```

Now I can access tables declared in the form of SCHEMA.TABLE such as INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.